# Why doesn't PHP str_replace match on my server for a certain string

Tags: php, apache, encoding, centos, str-replace

My server is CENTOS and running PHP 5.3.3 on Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)

I am trying to use str_replace and it doesn't work on a specific combination.

I have a string that is like

```
"revised - Unauthorized"
```

It will not match on

```
"d -"
```

It will match on

```
" - " 
" - U"
"d"
"d "
```

but if I have anything else in front even the full word revised it will not match all the way to the dash, so it seems to break at the dash. I tried this on PHPtest.net and it matched on everthing. So I don't know if this is a server issue or what the problem might be.

Comment: can you provide how you are using that function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. After comparing letter by letter there were actually two spaces in between the word revised and the -

Comment: would have been my first guess, too - but it could not be seen in the example you provided. next time, take care you present the data you actually have a problem with, and not something similar. (now accept your own answer so people know this question doesn't need anymore attention)